# Linear transformations are Lipschitz and continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm a little confused about the proofs that linear transformations $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are a) continuous and b) Lipschitz.

I know that Lipschitz implies continuity.

However, the only proof that linear transformations are Lipschitz that I've found uses continuity of $f$, which is a circular argument. The crux of this proof is showing that the Lipschitz constant is $\sup\limits_{|x|=1} |f(x)|$, where continuity is needed to show that $f$ is bounded on the compact set $|x|=1$. How can we reconcile this? Sorry if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: Continuity would mean $\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\|f(y)-f(x)\|=0$. Lipschitz continuity at $x$ means that there is a constant $M$ such that $\|f(y)-f(x)\|\le M\|y-x\|$ for all $y$ near $x$. Lipschitz continuity is normally more restrictive than ordinary continuity, unless you're dealing with linear transformation. A real function on the real line is Lipschitz continuous on $[a,b]$ with a uniform $M$ iff $f$ has a derivative a.e. on $[a,b]$ with derivative that is bounded a.e. by $M$; that's a much stronger condition than ordinary continuity.

Comment: @T.A.E. I understand that Lipschitz is stronger than ordinary continuity, but I was asking about how to prove that linear transformations are Lipschitz without using continuity (or vice versa).

Comment: (By the way I should have said iff $f$ is absolutely continuous with derivative a.e. which is bounded by $M$.) You normally use continuity at $0$ for $f$ to show that there is a constant $M$ such that $\|fx\|\le M\|x\|$ for all $x$. Then, by linearity, $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le M\|x-y\|$. For a matrix you can easily find such a bound from a bound on the matrix entries. The arguments are not really circular; the arguments show that a linear transformation on a normed linear space is continuous iff it is Lipschitz continuous (both hold in finite dimensions.)

Comment: @T.A.E. Oh ok, use the matrix entries, I see. Thank you!

Comment: This could help:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/881982/196067