# Lipschitz continuity of inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, continuity, inverse

Given a function f : $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, which is known to be Lipschitz continuous, can we say anything about the Lipschitz continuity of it's inverse function (in this case, the pseudoinverse matrix) ?

Comment: Lipschitz continuity from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself does not imply the inverse is Lipschitz.

Comment: What conditions must f satisfy to make the inverse also Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Requiring the derivative to be bounded below by some strictly positive number (or bounded above by some negative number) does it. It's not necessary, though.

Comment: In this case, the function is from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. How can one say it is bounded below by some positive number? Not being a square matrix, we can't even take a  determinant.

Comment: So you want your $f$ to be linear? Then the pseudoinverse is linear as well and hence Lipschitz continuous (as are all linear maps between finite-dimensional real or complex vector spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Every linear map $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is represented by a $(m\times n)$ matrix, say $A$. The [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of $A$ is equal to the Lipschitz constant of $f$, directly from  definitions.

Same holds for the linear map defined by the pseudoinverse matrix $A^\dagger$. The map is Lipschitz, with the Lipschitz constant   $\|A^\dagger \|$.

You should be aware that the linear transformation given by the pseudoinverse matrix $A^\dagger$ need not be an  inverse map in set-theoretical sense; i.e., $AA^\dagger$ and $A^\dagger A$ are generally not identity matrices.